# PHP - Is there any way for this login to be bypassed (Without bruteforcing)

Tags: php, security, server-side-attacks

```
<?php

$post = $_POST["post"];
$pass = "1234";

if ($post == $pass) {
    echo "Success!";

}else{
    echo "Failed.";
}
?>
```

**I know all about preparing statements and hashing etc. I always have security in mind, but I was thinking to myself one day, how would someone actually break into something like this? I understand you can SQL inject something database driven, but this of course is not database driven.**

But I was wondering how someone could actually break into this really simple login without just bruteforcing it?

Is there any kind of attack that could be done here to get into this login without any bruteforcing? Or would it be impossible otherwise.

Note:

I am of course excluding things such as putting a virus on the server, I mean within reason can a user with advanced technical knowledge somehow break into this?

Comment: Considering that `$post` isn't defined anywhere, no one's getting in.

Comment: I know, I will change it then, it was self explanatory I thought

Comment: You can still post to the file from a program like postman or a other file.

Comment: @SuperDJ No you couldn't SuperDJ, Patrick Q was completely correct in what he said

Comment: I have fixed the issue for Patrick anyway

Comment: Another user on the system may be able to read the file and get the password that way, a hash can help here.

Comment: Unless this is using HTTPS, a simple sniff would expose your password

Comment: Okay, so now the next question is, is the data being posted over HTTPS/SSL?  If not, then someone monitoring the network traffic could see the password

Comment: @Progrock Did you read my note I am excluding things such as that as I said

Comment: @RiggsFolly If my server was in the USA and the "hacker" was in the UK, how would he sniff this password, I am saying from a technical standpoint, is there any glitch or bug that would allow him to get in somehow?

Comment: I read your note.  Shared server, I could well grab that credential.  There may be another exploit that would allow me to read that file.

Comment: > "Another user on the system may be able to read the file and get the password that way."  -- or using a vulnerability in some other script file or form that would let a remote user echo the file contents.  That does not require a virus or even a login.

Comment: I can sniff any site in the universe from any PC in the universe

Comment: Keylogger on the client.

Comment: @Progrock Lets say this server was setup by me manually and it's in a different country (The server is not shared), my point with the notes is that I am saying there is no way to read the file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you explain how I would get this password sniffing a website, I don't see how it would work. Make it an answer.

Comment: You can't give an absolute such as 'no way'.

Comment: Unless the server is in a locked room and you have the only key there is always someone else that has access to your server

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely abstract and theoretical

Comment: Poisoned DNS....

Comment: Because you are posting the password to the site. Its possible to see anything that gets POST'ed or GET'ed with a sniffer

Comment: @Progrock My question is, how would this login be bypassed without accessing  the PHP file to get the password, I know someone could break into the office and steal my server and take the files, that is not what I want to hear.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I get you Riggs, but lets say nobody had ever actually logged in, and the hacker had to get in. (So there is no password to sniff)

Comment: Then there is no need for a password as nobody is ever using the site

Comment: You obviously only want the see the answer "No", so what's the point of this question?

Comment: So basically what I am gathering is that this is completely secure unless someone accesses your server and steals the file, finds a computer logging in to the site and sniffs the traffic or keylogs it or something

Comment: But there is no actual exploit to bypass this, that is what I was wanting to know.

Comment: It appears @PatrickQ is right, but you are definitely wrong

Comment: Someone accesses your source code.  Could be sitting in version control or on your laptop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See [timing attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack).

With PHP always use the [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function or another timing attack safe string comparer such as [`hash_equals()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php).

Comment: That is what I wanted to hear! Thanks!

Comment: This may be what you wanted to hear but this does *nothing to solve the issue you actually asked in your question*. For PHP to `hash` the input value it needs to read the raw input value. There is the gaping chasm that's unabridged....

Comment: @Martin wrong, he asked for some way to break in without bruteforce, and timing attack is indeed the solution here, that's not bruteforce.

Comment: @hanshenrik No... timing attacks is one of a number of ways; it's not an exclusive solution. There are many possible ways to catch the password before it reaches the PHP script that mitigates the timing attack risk.

Comment: @Martin nothing in OP's code is mitigating a timing attack. and in that code, the only vulnerability i see, is that it's vulnerable to timing attack. do you see any other vulnerability in his code? (also the timing attack would be 100% mitigated by doing `if (hash_equals(md5($post),md5($pass)){` - and here the md5 is only there for length padding, as [hash_equals is only constant-time when given 2 strings of the same length.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f9822b143e5726d5916223cc65842271b2b6ab2d/ext/hash/hash.c#L869))

Comment: Wouldn't this still require monitoring login attempts in order to gain the timing information?  OP already said "but lets say nobody had ever actually logged in".  Normally, yes, this would be a completely valid answer.  But so would all of the other vulnerabilities that OP categorically refused to consider.